# How to create a dictionary in python from a list and another dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list `mylist` and a dictionary `dict`, and i want to make another dictionary based on `mylist` and `dict`. How i can do that with dictionary comprehension since i need to keep track of two indexes? One for the keys of the dictionary and one for the range of the list? I tried the following:

```
new = {F(dict[k]):mylist[i] for k in dict, for i in range(len(mylist))}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but things like `l1` or `ll` make simply awful identifiers. Why risk difficult-to-track down bugs due to e.g. writing `l1` instead of `ll`?

Comment: @zondo Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()`:

```
new = {F(dict[key]): item for key, item in zip(dict, ll)}
```

You really shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name, though, since it conflicts with the built-in type.  `list` also is not a good name for the same reason.  Besides, what does it tell you about what is inside?  You should use descriptive names for both the list and the dictionary.

Comment: I agree with zondo's point about dict as a variable name, that's asking for trouble...

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with something like:

```
new = {F(dict[dict.keys()[i]]):ll[i] for i in range(len(ll))}
```

Comment: That won't work in Python3 since `.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object, not a list.

Comment: Good point, in python 3 you have to cast dict.keys() as a list... and the get the ith element.